# third-party plugins security risk mitigation

Tags: security, winapi, dll, plugins, add-on

suppose we have a highly extensible software using third-party plugins in the form of native DLLs(like a game engine or a CAD software), these dlls will gain the same privileges as the main app (correct me if in wrong), is there a way for the main application to intercept or restrict calls to winapi functions (fileIO, network communications...), I was thinking about [detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) but I didn't find anything on the internet suggesting that it is used for this purpose.

Comment: *these dlls will gain the same privileges as the main app* - yes. it will be use your process token. *intercept or restrict calls to winapi functions* - in general case - think task unreal.

Comment: The best you could do is to host the plugins in an external process, and control that process' access. I guess Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code follow this route, not so much for security but for reasons of stability.